# Limit google autocomplete only to 4 cities

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a booking website and i need to limit the google autocomplete suggestion only from 4 cities. I tried with .extend bounds but doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
  function autocompletePickup() {
  
    var bounds = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5200, 13.4050), radius: 20000
    });

    // var munchenBounds = new google.maps.Circle({
    //  center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.1351, 11.5820), radius: 20000
    // });

    var options = {
        bounds: bounds.getBounds(),
        strictBounds: true
    };

    var input = document.getElementById('pickup_address');
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    input.addEventListener("change", function() {

        console.log(autocomplete);
        input.value = "";
     
    });
  }
```

Does anyone have any idea how to extend the bounds with another 3 cities?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create your bounds as a `LatLongBounds` object that expects SouthWest and NorthEast coordinates. You can pick the coordinates between your four cities, let's say Hamburg (northern most), Berlin(eastern most), Cologne (western most), Munich (southern most):

```js
const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(48.1351, 6.9603), // SW Munich, Cologne
    new google.maps.LatLng(53.5511, 13.4050) // NE Hamburg, Berlin
);
```

And then fit your map to it:

```js
const options = {  
    strictBounds: true,
    bounds: bounds
};
map.fitBounds(bounds);
const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/y8f0r1wv/) on JsFiddle. If I try to search for Aachen for example, it doesn't show up.